# Can't compile scss file after upgrade to Angular Material 12

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

After upgrading our Angular project from Angular Material 11 to 12, our build script no longer compiles the scss files correctly.
Sass version: **1.42.1**
Command being run: **sass amber.scss amber.css**
Material now uses `@use '~@angular/material' as mat;`  at the top of each scss file, When trying to compile these files, I get the error: `Cannot find stylesheet @use '~@angular/material' as mat;`.
I have corrected this by providing the full path instead ie: `@use '../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming' as mat;`
Now, I am getting errors that the new mat functions for Angular Material 12 are undefined.
EG:  `Error undefined function: $primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$deep-purple-palette)';`
Here is my package.json:

```json
dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "^2.22.0",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "^8.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^7.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-material": "^4.41.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-messages": "^1.31.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.6",
    "npm": "6.14.15"
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this article. There you can set your older angular version , describe the complexity of your aplication and see all the steps that you need to follow in order to do a soft upgrade transition.

https://angular.io/guide/updating

I had a similar issue and after remove the line the error disappear